# How did Kevin Flynn not die of malnutrition?

Tags: tron-legacy

How does Kevin Flynn get all the nutrients a human body needs to survive. We see him eating dinner with Sam and Quorra. Quorra is eating and drinking the same as Sam and Kevin Flynn. And we can assume that Quorra gets the necessary nutrients to survive as a program from these mediums.

But, being in a digital world he is still presumably human as we see Sam bleed in the fight between Rinzler.

So considering that he human in the digital world, how is he getting the necessary nutrients to allow him to live?

Answer (score 5):

He is a digitized human, who consumes digital food.  The original movie showed him drinking digital water and getting refreshed and energized from it.

I don't recall any scenes where humans have different needs or rules than the "programs".

Additionally, when Quorra is "analoged" into the real world, she is apparently human and will need to live as a human.